# match end of line javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm probably doing something very stupid but I can't get following regexp to work in Javascript:

```
pathCode.replace(new RegExp("\/\/.*$","g"), "");
```

I want to remove // plus all after the 2 slashes.

Comment: Problem is with pathCode being multiline. I expected the $ to match on newline (\n), with the g flag set. So my question becomes:

Comment: How can remove the comments for each line separated by a newline (including the last line, optionally not ending with a new line).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems to work for me:

```
var str = "something //here is something more";
console.log(str.replace(new RegExp("\/\/.*$","g"), ""));
// console.log(str.replace(/\/\/.*$/g, "")); will also work
```

Also note that the regular-expression literal `/\/\/.*$/g` is equivalent to the regular-expression generated by your use of the `RegExp` object. In this case, using the literal is less verbose and might be preferable.

Are you reassigning the return value of `replace` into `pathCode`?

```
pathCode = pathCode.replace(new RegExp("\/\/.*$","g"), "");
```

`replace` doesn't modify the string object that it works on. Instead, it returns a value.

Comment: Problem was with multiline mode, the m switch did the trick in this case. Thank you (all) for your time!

Comment: Didn't see your comments until now. But yes, the `m` switch lets you match in multiline mode :)

Answer (score 4):

This works fine for me:

```
var str = "abc//test";
str = str.replace(/\/\/.*$/g, '');

alert( str ); // alerts abc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = a.replace(/\/\/.*$/, "");
```